# Is it possible to $expand endpoint for OData v4 WebApi 2 without including "Include" clause in entity framework 6 dbContext

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I notice that when I implemented an OData WebAPI GET Endpoint I'm able to use the $expand to grab navigation properties that are not shown by default.  However, the navigation properties would always be null.

I then did some digging and realized that this was because the way I was accessing the data via entity framework, that it was not pulling in the navigation properties unless I specified an "Include" clause.

```
DbContext.Entity.Include("NavigationProperty").ToListAsync()
```

Is there an easier way to get this working without having to specify in two locations what extra properties I want to retrieve? In otherwords, is there a way to setup the DBcontext to recongize the query parameters passed in via OData without having to do the "Include" clause?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

Define your `Get` method to return `IQueryable<T>` and decorate it with `EnableQuery` like so:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Entity> Get()
{
    return DbContext.Entity;
}
```

`EnableQuery` tells the OData framework to apply query composition, including `$expand` processing, to the query returned by the method.

Comment: Does this only happen if lazy loading is enabled with entity framwork?  [EnableQuery] filters at the OData WebAPI Layer.  However, don't you still need to expand at the Entity Framework DbContext Layer with Include when lazy loading is disabled or if you have a DTO layer where your not passing back the dbcontext directly.